# Calculating avg and sd for all columns in chunks for all columns

Tags: awk

Im trying to calculate avg and sd for all columns in chunks for all columns in a file using this:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

$1 != c1 {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if (c1) print s[i]/q[i]
    d = $1
    s[i] = q[i] = 0
    c1 = $1
}
}    
{
        s[i]+=$i
        if($i!="-")
            q[i]++
}
END {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        print d[i]"\t"s[i]/q[i]
}
```

in a file that looks like this:

```
chr x y z 
1 1 2 3
1 2 - 2
1 3 3 3
5a 2 2 3
5a 2 2 2
5a 3 3 3
```

So that I have an output like

```
chr x y z
1 2 2.5 2.3
5a 2.3 2.3 2.7
```

This is the error I get with real data

```
awk: avgchunks.awk:12: (FILENAME=wgcodnoncod_fst.table FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use scalar `s' as an array
```

Based on the accepted answer to this question and with his help, I expanded the answer to this question to also calculate SD

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
NR == 1 {
   print
   next
}
c1 != "" && $1 != c1 {
   printf "%s", c1
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      printf "%s%.2f%s%.2f", OFS, s[i]/q[i], OFS, sqrt(sq[i]/q[i] - (s[i]/q[i])^2)
   }
   print ""
   delete s
   delete q
   delete sq
}
{
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      s[i] += $i
      if($i != "-")
         sq[i] += $i * $i
         q[i]++
   }
   c1 = $1
}
END {
   printf "%s", c1
      for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      #sq[i] += $i * $i
      printf "%s%.2f%s%.2f", OFS, s[i]/q[i], OFS, sqrt(sq[i]/q[i] - (s[i]/q[i])^2)
   }
   print ""
}
```

Comment: when I run your code against the provided data I get a `division by zero` error; what is your `awk` version (`awk --version`)? other questions/issues: is `chr x y z` the first line of your file? your second block of code references `i` outside of a `for` loop (eg, `s[i]`, `$i`, `q[i]`) and while `awk` will still 'run' your likely not getting the desired results;  `d = $1` is a scalar ref to `d` while `d[i]` is an array reference ... so this is going to generate an error; I'm drawing a blank on the stated error re: `s` as a scalar vs array

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names in code you post that you want help with. Having to figure out what you mean by c1, d,, s, q, etc, is a significant deterrent to anyone willing to try to help you. Also make sure your indenting is correct to follow the control flow of your code. You should never have 2 `}`s one under the other at the start of lines for example and code within a `for` loop should never start at the same character position as the `for`, etc.

Comment: It's impossible for the code you posted to produce the error message you say it does and as @markp-fuso points out, when run with the input you provide it will produce a divide by zero error. Please help us to help you by providing readable code and sample input that produce the error message you want help debugging.

Comment: Yeah that was the error on real data. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script for computation:

```sh
cat avg.awk

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
NR == 1 {
   print
   next
}
c1 != "" && $1 != c1 {
   printf "%s", c1
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      printf "%s%.1f", OFS, s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1)
   }
   print ""
   delete s
   delete q
}
{
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      s[i] += $i
      if($i != "-")
         q[i]++
   }
   c1 = $1
}
END {
   printf "%s", c1
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      printf "%s%.1f", OFS, s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1)
   }
   print ""
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f avg.awk file

chr x   y   z
1   2.0 2.5 2.7
5a  2.3 2.3 2.7
```

---

For standard deviation use this awk script:

```sh
cat avg.awk

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
NR == 1 {
   print
   next
}
c1 != "" && $1 != c1 {
   printf "%s", c1
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      sq[i] = s[i] * s[i]
      printf "%s%.1f%s%.1f", OFS, s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1), OFS, sqrt(sq[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1) - (s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1))^2)
   }
   print ""
   delete s
   delete q
}
{
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      s[i] += $i
      if($i != "-")
         q[i]++
   }
   c1 = $1
}
END {
   printf "%s", c1
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      sq[i] = s[i] * s[i]
      printf "%s%.1f%s%.1f", OFS, s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1), OFS, sqrt(sq[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1) - (s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1))^2)
   }
   print ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add calculation for the standard deviation for this but it not works : `...
      printf "%s%.1f", OFS, "%s%.1f", OFS, s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1), sqrt(sq[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1) - (s[i]/(q[i]^2?q[i]:1)))
   }
   print ""
   delete s
   delete q
   delete sq
}
{
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      s[i] += $i
      sq[i] += $i*$i
        if($i != "-")
         q[i]++
   }
   c1 = $1
}
END {
   printf "%s", c1
   for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      printf "%s%.1f", OFS, "%s%.1f",  OFS, s[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1), sqrt(sq[i]/(q[i]?q[i]:1) - (s[i]/(q[i]^2?q[i]:1)))
   }
   print ""
}`

Comment: Sorry but what is formula for standard deviation?

Comment: this is what I use to calculate for individual columns 1 at a time `awk '{sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1} END {print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)^2)}' file`

Comment: Check my updated answer, I will check back tomorrow morning my time.

Answer (score 1):

As the calculation of the average and the standard deviation
share common steps, I've combined both. Please assign the variable
`type` in the `BEGIN` block to what you want to calculate.

```
func calc(c1, sx, sxx, n, nf,    ave, var, sd)
{
    printf("%s%s", c1, OFS)             # print label
    for (i = 2; i <= nf; i++) {
        if (n[i] == 0) {                # in case data is empty
            ave[i] = "-"
            sd[i] = "-"
        } else {                        # calculate based on formula
            ave[i] = sx[i] / n[i]
            var[i] = sxx[i] / n[i] - ave[i] * ave[i]
            if (var[i] < 0) sd[i] = 0   # variance is negative value
            else sd[i] = sqrt(var[i])
        }
        if (type == "ave")              # report depending on the type
            printf("%.1f%s", ave[i], i == nf ? "\n" : OFS)
        else
            printf("%.2f%s", sd[i], i == nf ? "\n" : OFS)
    }
}
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
    type = "ave"                        # assign to "ave" or "sd"
}
NR == 1 {
    print
    next
}
c1 != "" && $1 != c1 {                  # data set have changed
     calc(c1, sx, sxx, n, NF)           # then report with current data
     delete sx                          # initialize variables for next data
     delete sxx
     delete n
}
{
    c1 = $1                             # data set label
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "-") {
            sx[i] += $i                 # sum of x
            sxx[i] += $i * $i           # sum of x * x
            n[i]++                      # count of samples
        }
    }
}
END {
    calc(c1, sx, sxx, n, NF)
}
```

Result of the averages:

```
chr     x       y       z
1       2.0     2.5     2.7
5a      2.3     2.3     2.7
```

Result of the standard deviations:

```
chr     x       y       z
1       0.82    0.50    0.47
5a      0.47    0.47    0.47
```

Side notes:

- The variance, square of sd, theoretically has non-negative values.
  However it may be negative in computer calculation due to round-off
  errors. We need to take care of that when calculating the square root
  of the variance.
- When the number of samples (`n`) is less than 10, it may be better to
  change the denominator in the calculation of sd to `n - 1` for
  the better estimate of the standard deviation.
  It depends on your requirement or application.